Vega fit title into group mark container
In Vega the title seems to like being outside the group mark.  How can I get it to be inside the group mark?
Here's my attempt - Group 1 title is in a nested group however that didn't contain it within the parent group.  For the Group 2 title I used an offset to achieve the goal, however this seems an ugly way to do it... is there a more elegant way?

The code:
{
  "description": "Main vega chart",
  "width": 1280,
  "height": 1375,
  "padding": {
    "left": 35,
    "top": 15
  },
  "autosize": "pad",
  "background": {
    "signal": "c_background"
  },
  "signals": [
    {
      "name": "c_background",
      "value": "gray"
    },
    {
      "name": "c_foreground",
      "value": "white"
    },
    {
      "name": "pad_main",
      "value": 15
    }
  ],
  "layout": {
    "bounds": "flush",
    "padding": {
      "row": 15,
      "column": 15
    },
    "columns": 2,
    "align": "none"
  },
  "marks": [
    {
      "type": "group",
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "width": {
            "signal": "width/3"
          },
          "height": {
            "signal": "height/2"
          },
          "fill": {
            "signal": "c_foreground"
          },
          "fillOpacity": {
            "value": 1
          }
        }
      },
      "marks": [
        {
          "type": "group",
          "title": {
            "text": "Group 1",
            "baseline": "top",
            "anchor": "start"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "group",
      "title": {
        "text": "Group 2",
        "baseline": "top",
        "anchor": "start",
        "offset": {
          "signal": "-pad_main"
        }
      },
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "width": {
            "signal": "width/3"
          },
          "height": {
            "signal": "height/2"
          },
          "fill": {
            "signal": "c_foreground"
          },
          "fillOpacity": {
            "value": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}

